# How to transform values from a cell into new columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
| Image | Bounding Boxes                          |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
| a.jpg | xyz 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4                     |
| b.jpg | xyz 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 ijk 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
```

The values for those bounding boxes will always come in groups of five, where the values mean (in order)

- ID of the label represented by the bounding box
- X coordinate of the bounding box (as a percentage of image width)
- Y coordinate of the bounding box (as a percentage of image height)
- Width of the image (as a percentage of whole image)
- Height of the image (as a percentage of whole image)

Since each row will only have at most 5 such pairs (and at least zero), I'd like to transform the dataframe to look as follows:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+
| Image | L1  | x1  | y1  | w1  | h1  | L2  | x2  | y2  | w2  | h2  | ... | h5 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+
| a.jpg | xyz | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 |     |     |     |     |     |     |    |
| b.jpg | xyz | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | ijk | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.1 | ... |    |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

In other words, each of the space-separated values that used to be in one column, I'd like them split into a new column.

#### Question

How can this be done in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`str.split(' ', expand=True)`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on the space, and then join with the `Image` Column:

```
new_df = df[['Image']].join(df['Bounding Boxes'].str.split(' ', expand=True))

>>> new_df
   Image    0    1    2    3    4     5     6     7     8     9
0  a.jpg  xyz  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  None  None  None  None  None
1  b.jpg  xyz  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4   ijk   0.4   0.3   0.2   0.1
```

You can rename your columns as you see fit after that, using either `new_df.columns = ['my', 'list', 'of', 'column', 'names']` or `new_df.rename(columns={'old column name':'desired column name'})`